# How is JQuery library typically included in web page - whole or in part?

Tags: jquery

I am beginner in JavaScript and I am curious about the best way libraries like JQuery are used. Do you usually include the whole library in HTML page, so ~70KB (for JQuery) has to be downloaded every time a user visits your page? Or is there some heavy browser's cashing going on?

Comment: [relevant](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/139372/referencing-external-javascript-vs-hosting-my-own-copy/139380#139380).

Comment: Based on your answers, I guess developers usually put the whole file. Part of my question should have been: why don't they strip the file, to leave only functions which they are using? 70KB doesn't seem to be too small, even if it is heavily cashed, etc.

Comment: The difference is that a user may browse hundreds of pages that use the cached version. If every site used a customized minified version of jQuery, hundreds of pages would be loading 20kb-70kb files. It only takes about 3-4 pages before the full cached version is more effective.

Comment: @Ognjen If you load them from a CDN, 70 Kb does not matter. The user surely visited a site before that had jQuery loaded from a CDN, so it will not be loaded again, it will be read from cache. Stripping the jQuery file creates a nightmare when upgrading, methods can be dependant on each other, you may use plugins that expect the presence of the whole library, and of course, it's not really worth it.

Answer (score 1):

Load jQuery (minified) from a popular content-delivery network:

1. http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/cdn.ashx
2. https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide
3. http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery#CDN_Hosted_jQuery

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
    <title>My Site, using jQuery</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
```

By using one of these, it's likely the users visiting your site will not even have to download the file, as their browser may already have it cached from an earlier visit to another site using the same CDN.

Additionally, using one of these popular CDN's prevents you from having to maintain your version, or handle potentially-complicated tasks like setting up the appropriate headers to deal with compression.

Comment: thanks! btw. what does '...' mean in front of url in the example code?

Comment: @Ognjen Just that the full path is not visible. You would replace the `src="..."` value with the actual path to the jQuery file you're referring to. I've modified the answer to remove any confusion.

Comment: i thought it might have some special meaning :) ok, thanks again

Comment: @Ognjen Glad to be of help. If this answer solved your problem, please consider accepting it by clicking the check mark beside it.

Answer (score 0):

Minified jquery 1.7.2 is 93KB.
gzipped, that's 33KB

Properly served via a well-configured webserver, the web client will feel that 33KB hit once, and then it'll be cached.

This is a win for the client.  It's not too big in most circumstances.

If you're worried about serving it each time, get Google to do it for you. (this costs another socket setup, though): https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide